# Which Database to prefer for tree traversal?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

I am trying to create a smart interface where when user enter a street name, they get suggestion for locality,city(all cities containing same street name), state, country etc.

Right now I am trying to make it work on `MongoDB`, but have doubt on its performance.
I will appreciate any suggestion on, how to use `MongoDB` effectively or other databases better suitable for this purpose. i`m using Nosql as we need high efficiency.

Note. above example is hypothetical one, i need for multiple purpose, where connection can be complex.

Comment: sounds like any relational database - this is a straight forward type query

Comment: the example i gave is hypothetical one, i need it to work on multiple scenarios

Answer (score 2):

NoSQL databases are not the most efficient when you have relationships, they are most useful for having retrieval by key and denormalized databases, if you have relations in your data model the most efficient is a relational database (SQL)

Comment: What about Neo4j , i have been studying on it. It looks plausible for the use, is there any disadvantage it can have compared to relational DB ?